# Library system - Borrowing a book

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, system, bluej

I've been working on a library system for a few weeks now, but have a problem whilst trying to initialize the "borrow" feature for the system. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out. Here is the code I have so far for the "borrow" feature.

**Library class - includes faulty borrow**

private List collection;

```
public Library()
{
    collection = new ArrayList<Book>();
}

public void addBook(Book book)
{
    collection.add(book);
}

public String searchTitle(String titleSearch) {
    if (titleSearch == null) return "\n No Books Avaliable ";
    for(int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++){
        if(titleSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(collection.get(i).getTitle())){
            return collection.get(i).toString();
        }
    }
    return "\n No Books Avaliable "; //reachable only if no book found
}

public String toString()
{
    String total = "\n ";
    for (int i=0; i<collection.size(); i++)
    {
        Book b = collection.get(i);
        total = total + b.toString();
    }

    return total;
}
    public void borrowBook(String title) {
    int found = 0;
    for (Book b : collection) {
        if (collection.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            if (found == 0) {
                found = 1;
                }
            if (!book.isBorrowed()) {
                book.borrowed();
                found = 2;
                break;
            };
        }
    }
    if (found == 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.");
    } else if (found == 1) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
    } else if (found == 2) {
        System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + title);
    }
}
```

}

**This is the Book class**

```
public Book(int isbn, String author, String title, String genre, int  
 numcopies)
{

    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.numcopies = numcopies;


}

public int getISBN()
{
    return isbn;
}
public String getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public String getGenre()
{
    return genre;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "\nISBN: " +isbn + "\nAuthor: " +author + "\nTitle: " +title + 
  "\nGenre: " +genre + "\nNumber Of Copies " +numcopies +"\n ";
}
```

}

Comment: What's the specific problem you have ?

Comment: I am trying to implement a "borrow" feature into my library system. The code I have so far, for borrowing is giving me errors. Spent a sufficient amount of time on this, but finding it very hard to fix my mistake.

Comment: Also I am trying to reduce the number of copies by one every time someone takes out a book. So for example if there was 4 copies of a book and someone took one out, their would only be 3 left in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `borrowBook` method as

```
 public void borrowBook(String title) 
 {
    int found = 0;
    for (Book b : collection) 
    {
        if (b.getTitle().equals(title)) 
        {
           if (found == 0) 
    {
            found = 1;
        }
        if (!b.isBorrowed()) 
    {
            b.borrowed=true;
            found = 2;
            break;
        }
    }
}
    if (found == 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.");
    } else if (found == 1) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
    } else if (found == 2) {
        System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + title);
    }
}
```

and add `boolean borrowed` variable and `boolean isBorrowed()` method to `Book`  class where `isBorrowed()` will just return the value of `borrowed` variable.

Comment: This is my method isBorrowed in my book class. It's still not compiling for me                                                                                                                           public boolean isBorrowed()
    {
        return borrowed;
    }

Comment: Have you actually created the borrowed boolean? There isnt one in your question. boolean borrowed = false;

Comment: The error I am receiving is "Cannot find symbol - method borrowed", but in the book class i have this now.                                                                 public boolean isBorrowed()
    {
        boolean borrowed = false;
        return borrowed;
    }

Comment: Ok say I have used that code for the book class. The book class is working fine, but the "b.borrowed" part in your code for the library class is coming up with an error still.

Comment: ii will show error if you have it `borrowed` as a private variable...that part is just setting the value of that variable as true, you can try setter function as well or just change the access specifier

Comment: and also you have to change `private List collection;` to `private List<Book> collection;`

Comment: Ok so have changed the code around a bit here, and it seems to be working fine now. but the only problem is that I need to make it so that if we do in fact borrow a book, it will take 1 away from the number of copies. this is the code I used for "borrowing a book" http://paste.ofcode.org/vWAxmcAxER9k8n37sRyQE

Comment: so if you want to remove the borrowed book from the collection then just add `collection.remove(b)` under `if (!b.isBorrowed())` condition...change that methoad as: http://paste.ofcode.org/Txim4H8Gu6QqeUszVY74gh

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! its been great! One last thing, When I use the remove function it completely removes the book. Just wondering if there is a way so that if i have 4 copies, and then I borrow a book, it would reduce it to 3 copies?

Comment: When you remove a book from list you're left with 3 copies only?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. wasn't letting me on to my account. with the code you gave to remove the book, it literally removes the book from the system. But I want it to only reduce the number of the copies of that book by 1. So with your code to remove it, even if I have 4 copies available, it completely removes all the copies of the book.

Comment: Then instead of `collection.remove(b)` in borrowing method use `b.numcopies -=1`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (collection.getTitle().equals(title))
```

to

```
if (b.getTitle().equals(title))
```

Right now you are calling the getTitle method on the collection, instead of the particular book you are currently on in your iteration.

You also appear to be missing an isBorrowed method.

Comment: Changed "if (collection.getTitle().equals(title))" to "if (b.getTitle().equals(title))" and it works! Thanks. But yeah I am very stuck on creating an isBorrowed method.

Comment: @JohnMackinnon - If you are trying to do something really simple you could just use a boolean and change it to true for borrowed or false for not borrowed. This is a very simplistic way of doing it. You would then have to search the entire collection to try to find a book with that title that has a borrowed status of false. I think you'd be better of using a database rather than a collection.